# Extract multiple substrings from one semi random string

Tags: ssis

I am working with a dump of an AD from my business. I am given Username, Name, and Groups. My end goal is to have the csv file dumped on a regular basis, my SSIS package grabbing it, removing all the trash from the Groups and then having a report feed off of it so that a user can search for someones name or username and it will list the groups they belong to.

The issue I am running into is that the groups section is filled with a lot of trash for example I am given something like this:

```
CN=Standards of Conduct,CN=Users,DC=rlhk,DC=local|CN=ManagementLevel-9,OU=Groups,OU=rem,DC=rlhk,DC=local
```

This is a very short one(some are upwards of 3000 characters). The parts from this one that I would like to extract are Standards of Conduct and ManagementLevel-9. I say this is semi random because obviously not everyone belongs to the same groups and I don't believe they are all in the same order.

The Group always follows immediately after |CN=, the very first occurence doesn't have a | in front it is just CN=.

I've tried something like:

```
SUBSTRING(Groups,FINDSTRING(Groups,"|CN=",1 ) + 3,FINDSTRING(Groups,",",1) - 4)
```

However it only gets the first iteration of "|CN=" obviously and I'm not sure how to get all of them.

Thank you

Comment: The first two CN=XXXXXX don't have a | character in front of them, I would ignore the pipe character altogether and just search for CN={capture}.

Comment: Valid point. I'm just unsure as to what the best method for searching through the string and extracting all of those would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex code below will match your groups if they follow the rules you outlined. The Regex will search the input string for all instances of CN= followed by everything up to a comma.

```
    string groupString = "CN=Standards of Conduct,CN=Users,DC=rlhk,DC=local|CN=ManagementLevel-9,OU=Groups,OU=rem,DC=rlhk,DC=local";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(groupString , @"CN=([^,]*)"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is another version (non-console) which captures the results in a `List<string>` so you can iterate over it or perhaps check if a specific value is contained in it:

```
        string groupString = "CN=Standards of Conduct,CN=Users,DC=rlhk,DC=local|CN=ManagementLevel-9,OU=Groups,OU=rem,DC=rlhk,DC=local";
        List<string> matchedGroups = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(groupString , @"CN=([^,]*)"))
        {
            matchedGroups.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
        //Use the matchedGroups collection here
```

To use this in an SSIS package, you will add a Script Component as a Transformation and then on the Input Columns tab, check the box that corresponds to that field, i.e. distinguishedname and indicate it is ReadWrite.

```
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(Row.distinguishedname, @"CN=([^,]*)"))
    {
        Row.distinguishedname = (match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

If this is to be a new column, then you will need to go into the Inputs and Outputs tab, expand Output 0, select Output Columns, click Add Column and then provide it a new name and data type (simplifiedName, DT_STR 3000 codepage 1252). Then we would change the above line to

```
        Row.simplifiedName = (match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Don't forget to add a reference to the RegularExpressions assembly `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: I apologize as this is the first time I have used a script component. This runs fine, however my output is the same as my input. Is there something simple I am forgetting to do?

Comment: @Bartimeus I edited my response so it would capture the results in a List<string> which you can then use.

Comment: I've edited the answer to shed light on how to use the regex inside of SSIS. Hope that clarifies that answers your question @Bartimeus

Comment: I really appreciate you guys helping so much. I'm not sure what you mean by "Use the matchedGroups collection here".                             Thank you thank you so much for all the help so far!

Comment: I finally got it working. I used 

`Row.Groups = string.Join(", ", matchedGroups.ToArray());`